# Ends of long tags get cut off on iOS app

Tags: bug, ios-app

We recently were talking about really long tags over on Arqade, and I found a bit of a bug when dealing with tags that are exceedingly long. Notably on my answer [here](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12499/127901) listing a bunch of game names that exceeded our old limit of 25 characters for a tag. The longer of the tags (the ones exceeding 37 characters and are in a bulleted list) get clipped instead of wrapping to the next line, or being able to scroll to see the rest of the tag. Can we get the tags to wrap or be able to scroll?

[image: example of bug]

Answer (score 2):

- This is more than the new limit of 35 characters, so there won't be real tags with such a long name.
- What you expect to happen exactly? Have the tag span two lines? That would be ugly.

Bottom line: not a bug in my opinion. Just don't put such long names, and if you  put, don't expect it to be displayed properly.